# CSS selector ::selection is not using given background color

Tags: html, css, colors

I am trying to make some RGB text, and that works, however when I am trying to make a `::selection` then it will hide the text, and will for some reason take the background color of the text. I have tried anything I can think of, for now, I am making it for chrome and will later work on firefox.

## Research

In my research, I have found that you do not need to use a selector like `.rgb`. While looking into some documentation/examples, I have encountered multiple weird things, like when I was using `.rgb::selection` I could not higlight/select ANY text on the screen.

when I looked into W3schools they simply use

```css
::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
```

and it works. Ive asked my teachers, and my peers. What none of them understand is why the `::selection` is taking the animate property. What I have thought is that when I use `-webkit-background-clip` that is what is making it not work properly. If this is the case then how can I make it so that it still takes it. When I read some more, I tryed to use `!important`, this was the closest that I got. It made the text white, but the color was still changing in the background. I've looked [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) to try to learn how i can use it properly, but i think I have used it correctly. I just cant seem to get the background color to stay one color.

This is what I have gotten so far.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.rgb
{
  position:fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #008AFF, #00FFE7);
  animation:animate 10s forwards infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

::selection !important{
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

@keyframes animate
{
  0%, 100%
  {
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  50%
  {
    filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="rgb">Welcome to my webpage</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've looked all over this site for something or someone with this problem but it seems I'm a first.

Comment: Take a close look at your CSS in comparison to your HTML. For example, div .rgb doesn't exist - there is no element with class rgb that is a child of a div. You can look up the various types of combinators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators Spaces are very significant.

Comment: `<div class="rgb" />` - this was just a test that I had forgotten to remove, but it is there, and I am sorry I forgot to remove it, however in css that is selecting all divs, then filtering them down to all divs with class "rgb" ? @AHaworth

Comment: My question has been updated to remove that sorry

Comment: You are using `!important` incorrectly. It goes after each property, not the selector rule. Like `background: red !important;`. Since you are using a background animation and text-fill, you need to unset those properties in the selection. You can't simply overwrite the color.

Comment: Ah, when I try that though it brings me back to where I was, and when I enter the code there it will simply not show me the text and just cover up the text and not make it white again.

Comment: My guess is that selection does not mix well with CSS filters. Without the animation and text clip, it works as expected. Looks to work this way in all browsers.

Comment: Okay thanks, ill see if there is any way possible to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape the filter' a somewhat hacky way of doing it might be to have a second copy of the heading which is placed over the original and is actually the element for which selection takes place.

Its text and background are transparent until there is a selection at which point the selection (only) becomes white and red respectively.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.rgb {
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #008AFF, #00FFE7);
  animation: animate 10s forwards infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.shadow {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.shadow::selection {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="rgb">Welcome to my webpage</h1>
<h1 class="shadow">Welcome to my webpage</h1>
```